# Explanation for Eigenvalues or Characteristic values of Projection Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, independence, projection-matrices

**Question:** I need to give what are possible eigenvalues/characteristic value of projection operator with an explanation.

**My Attempt:** 
Let *E* be any projection on vector space *V*. Assume *R* be the range of *E* and *N* be null space of *E*
[image]

**My Doubt:**

- I have got c=1 and c=0;
- there is ***and*** in between by the condition of independence
- so how does this imply **c is either 1 or 0**

Please help me in understanding *how the above equation gives that c has possible eigenvalue either 0 or 1*.

Comment: Any reason that we're not using the fact that $E^2 = E$, so any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $E$ must satisfy $\lambda^2 = \lambda$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog we can use that too but I was trying with some other ways to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah no, you are forgetting something.

You wrote that $\alpha \in R, \beta \in N$ so they must be independent. *This is not true unless both are non-zero vectors!*

So if $\alpha  = 0$, then of course $\alpha \in R$ but $\alpha$ won't be independent of $\beta$, even if $\beta \in N$.

Therefore, while the equation $(1-c)\alpha + c\beta = 0$ is correct, you need to now make exceptions for potentially one of $\alpha,\beta$ being zero.

So if $\alpha = \beta = 0$ then $v = 0$ : but $v$ is an eigenvector, so by definition $v \neq 0$.

If $\alpha = 0$ then $\beta \neq 0$ so the equation becomes $c \beta = 0$ which gives $c = 0$.

If $\beta = 0$ then $\alpha \neq 0$ so the equation becomes $(1-c)\alpha = 0$ which gives $c = 1$.

Both $\alpha , \beta \neq 0$ is not possible, since this would lead to $c=0$ and $c=1$  which is not possible.

Thus, the accurate conclusion would be the following : given a projection operator $E$ with decomposition $R + N$, any eigenvector $v$ either :

- belongs to $R$ with eigenvalue $1$ , or
- belongs to $N$ with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: I must thank you for this question : this exposes a potential mistake that I shall point out to a few people in future.